# Could not install laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to install laravel in windows. In composer.phar, opening it in msdos, i input the following command as suggested by documentation:

```
composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"
```

but i am getting the following error:

> Could not open input file: '*

Comment: what is your operating system?

Comment: @Md. Sahadat Hossain windows 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to install [composer](https://getcomposer.org/)

Assuming that you use `xampp` for webserver and your webserver directory is `C:\xampp`.

Here is the steps:

> Step 01: open command line tools and change your directory to
>   webserter using this command `cd C:\xampp\htdocs`
>
> Step 02: run this command `composer create-project laravel/laravel
>   projectname`

Here replace `projectname` with your actual project name.

Comment: when i run that above command nothing happens.only the blink in next line,

Comment: only the blink in next line

Comment: maybe you do not install composer properly.

Comment: i don't think so. when i try to reinstall, it displayed 'already installed' like message.

Comment: i uninstalled and then reinstalled it in C:xampp/php as php.exe file is in there and used above code cd c:\xampp\php and the project is created. how or should i move it to htdocs.

Answer (score 0):

If have installed composer on different directory(not in C: drive),

```
Step 1: change directory to location where composer.json exist.

eg: D:\xampp\htdocs\project\composer.json then change to D:\xampp\htdocs\project

Step 2: command=>php composer.phar install
```

Comment: I have installed composer in C drive.